# Program hangs upon removal of a object from a HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, bukkit

I develop plugins for Minecraft servers. Recently on my test server, I've been having repeated crashes while removing objects from an ArrayList or Hashmap.

First, it just appeared to be a single removal of something from an ArrayList. However, it now appears to be able to happen randomly upon the removal of something from any ArrayList/HashMap.

In this particular instance, the line of code is `entlist.get(pl.getName()).remove(en);` with the surrounding code being

```
for (LivingEntity en: remove) {
    i++;
    if (entlist.containsKey(pl.getName())) {
        entlist.get(pl.getName()).remove(en);
    }
    if (i > 2000) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Too many entities to remove!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

entlist is a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<LivingEntity>> entlist = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<LivingEntity>>();`.

The tread dump specifically lists `ArrayList#remove()` as being the problem.

```
[09:53:51 ERROR]: Current Thread: Server thread
[09:53:51 ERROR]:       PID: 14 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: RUNN
ABLE
[09:53:51 ERROR]:       Stack:
[09:53:51 ERROR]:               java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:481)
[09:53:51 ERROR]:               a.e$4.run(Main.java:1786) //Line 1786 being the `entlist.get(pl.getName()).remove(en);` line from earlier.
```

Java version:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -version
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Also since someone in the comments asked, [I've pastebinned the entire thread dump that Spigot puts out](http://pastebin.com/tMSi0PMz) when it detects the freeze.

Why is a simple removal of a value from an ArrayList/HashMap freezing the entire server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what line 481 of ArrayList is, but on the assumption that it is [this one](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java/#481), it is difficult to see how the `ArrayList.remove(...)` call is "freezing".

I have two theories:

- Something is performing updates to the `ArrayList` without synchronizing properly.  That can result in another thread seeing stale / inconsistent state for the `ArrayList`, leading to unpredictable behaviour.  This *might* be enough to put the `remove` operation into an infinite loop, though it is not immediately obvious how.

  It could also be that a `HashMap` update that isn't synchronized.
- The application is not freezing at all.  Instead it is taking *a very long time* ... because you have a very large data structure and/or a very expensive `equals` operation.

  You could test this theory (in part) by looking at the sizes of the data structures and/or measuring and logging the times taken by that section of the code.

Comment: I've spent hours trying to make everything synchronized - It's just not possible. I'm going to have to use a ConcurrentHashMap :(.

Comment: +1 for the second theory. The crash, being an unlikely one to happen, may as well be caused by a bad algorithm.

Comment: I eventually solved this about a month later, by using the addAll() method instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't shed any light onto what the real problem was in the first place.  What you were doing was facially equivalent to `addAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you say this is happening randomly, but always on the List.remove line, this is likely a concurrency issue, where somewhere else in your program another Thread is iterating through the List. So when you call remove(), you're gonna have a ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: But, why would a concurrency issue freeze the server instead of throwing an error? Also I believe concurrency would be impossible, due to the fact that Spigot is a single-threaded application (I can still check though).